# Do I need to remove breakpoints before building release exe?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm testing a Visual Studio C# program mostly in debug mode with breakpoints. Sometimes I need to build the release version .exe to run some tests, but then go back to testing in debug mode.

Before I build the release version I'm not removing my breakpoints. Is there any reason to remove the breakpoints? Does anything carry over to the release exe? I don't see anything, but i just want to be sure.

Thanks!

Comment: No they don't carry over, they aren't stored in the exe file even in debug mode

Comment: @Rhumborl Good to know, thank you! Should I delete this question? It's being downvoted. Was it wrong to ask or something? I didn't see any related questions...

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with your question, and it prompted a good answer. Unfortunately some people have a tendency to downvote questions they think are too simplistic, forgetting they were a beginner once, before they became arrogant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in the good old days, you could have an `INT 3` machine instruction in the binary code of exe and dll files, which is the assembly definition of a breakpoint and would (and still will) cause to break into a debugger. No .NET compiler/linker does that. Actually, it cannot - because managed exe files contain IL which is just-in-time compiled.
In .NET and especially in the Microsoft environment, breakpoints are a feature of the IDE in connection with 
the runtime, and never end up in the binary.

An old, but thorough writeup of the mechanism of managed breakpoints can be found here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2004/12/28/how-do-managed-breakpoints-work/

Breakpoints are stored in a configuration file of the VS solution only for convenience (so developers would not lose their breakpoitns between Visual Studio sessions).

In contrast, a `Debug.Assert` call *can* cause harm in release builds, if used or configured incorrectly.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the details!